# Track what documents are coming from which shards in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have enabled routing and all my sets of documents are going to same shard. Now i need to directly hit that machines and see if there is performance gain . But then i haven't found a mechanism to find what document went to which shard. Kindly let me know if there is any way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Search Shards API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-shards.html).

Sample Syntax:

```
GET /index/type/_search_shards?routing={routing_id}
```